# Splitting a data frame by depending on the two columns and applying some operations on the sub groups

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

my data frame look like this:

[image: Short View of Data]

An item in PlantProduct (means plant); can have multiple material numbers
 What i want to do:

1. Group the data frame with respect to PlantProduct and MaterialNumber, in other words, split them into data frames.
2. If an element's length of the group member is less than 10, than drop it
3. So at the end of the work, I should have a kind of list elements  that contains only this kind of data frames:

[image: grouped data]

4. After having these data frame, I am going to perform more additional operations; like graphing, and time series forecasting all over the list elements (shown in picture -2)

The thing I done is th following:

```
      df.groupby(by=['PlantProduct','MaterialNumber']).apply(lambda x:len(x)>10)
```

However, this script creates a grouped data frame object and I am not able to perform any operation on it.

to help I am writing down my script here, but I must do it in python as well, as you can guess I am not a python expert.

My R code:

```
#split 1st due to PlantProduct

    mylist <- split(res2, res2$PlantProduct)

#second split due to MaterialNumber

      for(name in names(mylist))
      mylist[[name]] <- split(mylist[[name]], mylist[[name]]["MaterialNumber"])
      mylist[[name]] <- mylist[[name]][sapply(mylist[[name]], function(x) nrow(x)[[1]]) > 10]
    } 

#Encoding 0 values with NA, all over the list elements

    for(name in names(mylist)) {
      for(name2 in names(mylist[[name]]))
      {
        mylist[[name]][[name2]][,4] <- ifelse(mylist[[name]][[name2]][,4] == 0, NA, mylist[[name]][[name2]][,4])
      }
    }

#creating a date index column and joining it with the list element

    for(name in names(mylist)) {
      for(name2 in names(mylist[[name]]))
      {
        mydate <- data.frame(seq(min(as.Date(mylist[[name]][[name2]][,3])), as.Date('2018-05-01'), by = "month"))
        colnames(mydate) <- "ds"
        mylist[[name]][[name2]] <- left_join(mydate, mylist[[name]][[name2]], "ds")
        rm(mydate)
      }
    }

#time series forecasting on individual list elements

    for(name in names(mylist)) {
      for(name2 in names(mylist[[name]]))
      {
      m <- prophet(mylist[[name]][[name2]])
      future <- make_future_dataframe(m, periods = 1, freq = "month")
      forecast <- predict(m, future)
      a <- data.frame(tail(forecast[c('ds', 'yhat', 'yhat_lower', 'yhat_upper')], n = 365))
      a$ds <- as.Date(a$ds, "%Y-%m-%d")
      mylist[[name]][[name2]] <- left_join(a, mylist[[name]][[name2]], "ds")
      rm(m, future, forecast, a)
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to [`GroupBy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and preserve the original structure, use [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html) instead, from the documentation:

> Return a copy of a DataFrame excluding elements from groups that do not satisfy the boolean criterion specified by func.

So instead do:

```
df.groupby(['PlantProduct', 'MaterialNumber']).filter(lambda x: len(x) > 10)
```

Here's a toy example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1], 'b':[2,2,2,3,3,3,1]})
```

Using [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
df.groupby(['a', 'b']).apply(lambda x: len(x) >= 2)

a  b
1  1    False
   2     True
   3     True
dtype: bool
```

This returns a set of `booleans` for each group as you are applying a condition.

However using [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html) the result of this condition will be used to filter the original dataframe:

```
df.groupby(['a', 'b']).filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 2)

   a  b
0  1  2
1  1  2
2  1  2
3  1  3
4  1  3
5  1  3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can using `transform`

```
df=df[df.groupby(['PlantProduct', 'MaterialNumber']).PlantProduct.transform('count')>10]
```

---

Test Frame from nixon

```
df[df.groupby(['a','b']).a.transform('count')>2]
Out[203]: 
   a  b
0  1  2
1  1  2
2  1  2
3  1  3
4  1  3
5  1  3
```